# Canadian living in US: can I work for my Canadian business?

Tags: visas, usa, canadian-citizens

I've been approved for a TN1 visa. I will be moving from British Columbia to California. I know I'm authorized to work for a particular company (my sponsor) and no other. What I'm unsure about is if I'm allowed to to continue to do work for my own company which is registered in BC. It's an online business, so I can work from anywhere.

Comment: It is a grey area however people routinely visit the USA and do online work.

Comment: Does your sponsor allow for that kind of work? A lot of the big companies have contracts which basically state that all work that you do is their IP.

Comment: @nikhil such provisions are generally unenforceable, at least under US law.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments. Putting on hold.